# Is there a "proper" way to convert django.db.models.query.ValuesListQuerySet to a pure List?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm attempted to delete records from a number of models in a single method, were I have the following schema:

```
picture 1:1 picture_foreign_picture *:1 picture_foreign
```

I'm deleting these given list picture_foreign objects:

```
picture_foreign_pictures = PictureForeignPicture.objects.filter(picture_foreign__in=picture_foreigns)
picture_ids = picture_foreign_pictures.values_list('picture_id', flat=True)
logger.warn('PICTURES REMOVE: %s' % picture_ids)
picture_foreign_pictures.delete()
logger.warn('PICTURES REMOVE: %s' % picture_ids)
```

The 2 loggers lines output the following:

```
WARNING 2013-01-02 03:40:10,974 PICTURES REMOVE: [86L]
WARNING 2013-01-02 03:40:11,045 PICTURES REMOVE: []
```

Despite this however, the picture `86` still exists:

```
mysql> select id from picture where id = 86;
+----+
| id |
+----+
| 86 |
+----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I guess I could get around this by simply converting `picture_ids` into a pure integer list however I'm wondering whether there's a more Django method to this? I would have thought `flat=True` would already handle this but it seems to be more than just a pure list.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure it's proper, but it's ridiculously simple to use `list()` to accomplish this:

```
picture_ids = list(picture_foreign_pictures.values_list('picture_id', flat=True))
```

Comment: above operation is raising an error: Error in argument:

Comment: @Arun I got the `*** Error in argument` error when I was debugging  with pdb, because pdb override the keyword `list`. In the *real world*, this solution works.

Comment: It will touch the database to convert. This is a problem because, if the ValueListQuerySet is a subquery of another query, it will touch the database before it needs to.

Comment: Thanks @Leonardo.Z, pdb override brought me here - you saved me from a rabbit hole.

Answer (score 5):

Above solution is not working:

You can convert to pur list like this:

```
p_ids =PictureForeignPicture.objects.filter(picture_foreign__in=picture_foreigns).values_list('picture_id', flat=True)

new_list = [];new_list.extend(p_ids)
```

Comment: What python/django are you using? I think my solution was on Python 2.7 / Django 1.4 ?